# Tkinter create buttons from list each with its own function

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

I want to create buttons from a list and assign each button a function based on the list item. I tried below and the button doesn't respond to a click. I see solutions where a lambda function is used to pass a parameter to a function but I would like separate functions. Using Python 3.5 in Anaconda

```
import tkinter as tk

def North():
    print('slected North')

def South():
    print('slected South')

def East():
    print('slected East')

def West():
    print('slected West')

lst = ['North','South','East','West']
win = tk.Tk()
win.title = 'Compass'
for col,Direction in enumerate(lst):
        butName = tk.Button(win, text = Direction, command = Direction)
        butName.grid(row = 1, column = col)


win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list contains *strings*; it needs to contain *functions*

```
lst = [North,South,East,West]
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster and better:

```
import tkinter as tk

def onbutton_click(label):
    print('selected ', label)

lst = ['North','South','East','West']
win = tk.Tk()
win.title = 'Compass'
for col,Direction in enumerate(lst):
    butName = tk.Button(win, text=Direction, command=lambda e=Direction: onbutton_click(e))
    butName.grid(row=0, column=col)

win.mainloop()
```

or your way:

```
import tkinter as tk

def North():
    print('slected North')

def South():
    print('slected South')

def East():
    print('slected East')

def West():
    print('slected West')

lst = [North, South,East, West]
win = tk.Tk()
win.title = 'Compass'
for col,Direction in enumerate(lst):
    butName = tk.Button(win, text=Direction.__name__, command=Direction)
    butName.grid(row=0, column=col)

win.mainloop()
```

I also set the row as 0 cause there is no need to be 1.