# How do you update Tkinter parameters for buttons and labels created in a loop?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, label

Once an instance of a button has been created in a loop how is an individual button or label updated? Lets say I want to change the background on the 'North' button to 'blue'.

```
?????????.config(bg = 'blue')
```

What is the button name for the 'North' button in the code below?

```
import tkinter as tk

def onbutton_click(label):
    print('selected ', label)

lst = ['North','South','East','West']
win = tk.Tk()
win.title = 'Compass'
for col,Direction in enumerate(lst):
    buttonName = tk.Button(win, text=Direction, command=lambda e=Direction: onbutton_click(e))
    buttonName.grid(row=0, column=col)

win.mainloop()
```

This code is from another question answered by gms - thank you, that was a great answer, very clear!
[Tkinter create buttons from list each with its own function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182356/tkinter-create-buttons-from-list-each-with-its-own-function)

Answer (score 2):

You need some sort of reference to the button objects in order to access and modify them, after they are created in the loop.

One idea is to put them inside a dictionary whose key is the direction:

```
import tkinter as tk
    
def onbutton_click(label):
    print('selected ', label)

lst = ['North','South','East','West']
win = tk.Tk()
win.title = 'Compass'

button_dict = {}

for col,Direction in enumerate(lst):
    buttonName = tk.Button(win, text=Direction, command=lambda e=Direction: onbutton_click(e))
    buttonName.grid(row=0, column=col)
    button_dict[Direction] = buttonName

button_dict['North'].config(bg='blue')

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why did you use `button_dict[Direction] = buttonName` instead of `button_dict.update({Direction: buttonName})`? Just curious

Comment: @TheLizzard It's essentially two ways to achieve the same thing. I prefer setting the key-value pair directly onto the dictionary when I only have a single pair. I'd use `dict.update` if I had multiple key-value pairs to update, or if I already had a dictionary beforehand (no need to create a dictionary with a single key-value pair, just to use it to update another dictionary and then forget about it - just set the value directly). Ultimately it doesn't really matter, though.

Comment: That looks very clean and easy to understand. Thanks jfaccioni!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def onbutton_click(label):
    print('selected ', label)
    if label == "North":
        # because "North" is the first item of `lst` we
        # know that we can use 0 as the idx
        buttons[0].config(text="new text here")

lst = ['North','South','East','West']
win = tk.Tk()
win.title = 'Compass'

# Create a list for all of the buttons
buttons = []

for col,Direction in enumerate(lst):
    buttonName = tk.Button(win, text=Direction, command=lambda e=Direction: onbutton_click(e))
    buttonName.grid(row=0, column=col)

    buttons.append(buttonName)

win.mainloop()
```

I created a dictionary of all of the buttons and directions like this: `{"North": <Button>, "South": <Button>}`. Then I used `<dict>["North"]` to get the button with the "North" label.

Comment: Just thinking out loud, would it be possible to use a list or tuple instead of a dictionary? Thanks for the input Lizzard!

Comment: @FordF-100 yes I will change my answer to use a list. If you still need the answer with a dictionary, use jfaccioni's answer.

Comment: Y'all are super helpful!

Comment: StackOverFlow :D